# ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes in Python

Tags: python

OLD ERROR:
I've got this error:

> ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:

And this is my code. I want to convert the String ResultPart on a dict:

```
 resultPart = '{"sentences": [{"parsetree": [], [("words": "Q", {"Lemma": "q", "NamedEntityTag": "O", "CharacterOffsetEnd": "1", "PartOfSpeech": "NN", "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"})], "dependencies": [], "text": "Q", "parsetree": [], "indexeddependencies": []}]}'
 resultPart2 = json.dumps(resultPart)
 #result should be a dict
 result = json.loads(resultPart)
```

EDIT: I corrected that part and now I've this error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is the new code:

```
 resultPart = "{'sentences': [{'words': [('Q', {'Lemma': 'q', 'NamedEntityTag': 'O', 'CharacterOffsetEnd': '1', 'PartOfSpeech': 'NN', 'CharacterOffsetBegin': '0'})], 'dependencies': [], 'text': 'Q', 'parsetree': [], 'indexeddependencies': []}]}"
 resultPart2 = json.dumps(resultPart)
 result = json.loads(resultPart2)
```

Comment: You seem to have a `(` where I'd expect a `{`. Why are you creating the JSON by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be at the following line:

```
{
...
    "parsetree": [], [
    "words": "Q", {
        "Lemma": "q",
        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "1",
        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
    }],
...

}
```

It is looking for another `key` after the `[]` as the value for `"parsetree"`. So it will need to be something like the following to be valid JSON.

```
{
...
    "parsetree": [], 
    "more_words": [
    "words": "Q", {
        "Lemma": "q",
        "NamedEntityTag": "O",
        "CharacterOffsetEnd": "1",
        "PartOfSpeech": "NN",
        "CharacterOffsetBegin": "0"
    }],
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't related to the error, but it will help.

You are dumping a string to another string as JSON... which will result in escape characters.

```
>>> s = '{"dependencies": [], "sentences": [{"parsetree": []}], "text": "Q"}'
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(s)
'"{\\"dependencies\\": [], \\"sentences\\": [{\\"parsetree\\": []}], \\"text\\": \\"Q\\"}"'
```

I highly doubt that is what you want. That being said, make a Python dictionary instead because 1) It is less error-prone and 2) You can get the correct JSON

```
>>> s = {1: 2, 'sentences': [{'parsetree': []}], 'dependencies': [], 'text': "Q"}
>>> json.dumps(s)
'{"1": 2, "dependencies": [], "sentences": [{"parsetree": []}], "text": "Q"}'
```